# Unity ads не показывается на андроид

Tags: c#

Добавил рекламу от unity ads . В редакторе юнити все работает , но на телефоне нет . Я отключил тестовый режим и в коде и во вкладке Servises . Не помогло . Вот детальная информация :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class InterstitialAds : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
{

    [SerializeField] private string androidAdID = "Interstitial_Android";
    [SerializeField] private string iOSAdID = "Interstitial_iOS";

    private string adID;

    void Awake()
    {
        adID = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
            ? iOSAdID
            : androidAdID;
        LoadAd();
    }

    public void LoadAd()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading Ad: " + adID);
        Advertisement.Load(adID, this);
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        Debug.Log("Showing Ad: " + adID);
        Advertisement.Show(adID, this);
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string placementId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
    {
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string placementId)
    {
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string placementId)
    {
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string placementId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
    {
        LoadAd();
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string placementId)
    {
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string placementId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
    {
    }
}
```

Второй код :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdsInitializer : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsInitializationListener
{

    [SerializeField] string androidGameID = "5092429";
    [SerializeField] string iOSGameID = "5092428[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]";
    [SerializeField] bool testMode = false;
    private string gameID;

    void Awake()
    {
        InitializeAds();
    }
    public void InitializeAds()
    {
        gameID = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) ? iOSGameID : androidGameID;
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameID, testMode, this);
    }

    public void OnInitializationComplete()
    {
        Debug.Log("Unity Ads initialization complete.");
    }

    public void OnInitializationFailed(UnityAdsInitializationError error, string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Unity Ads Initialization Failed: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
    }
}
```

Ошибок никаких нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй сменить страну(в настройках+прокси). в России сейчас нет рекламы через гугл

Comment: Я вам уже редактировал прошлый вопрос с некорректной вставкой кода. Вы же могли посмотреть, как верно оформить код? Но почему-то проигнорировали, и снова я вношу одни и те же правки, чтобы устранить те же самые проблемы с форматированием кода, как в прошлом вопросе.

Comment: Извините ! Но всё же может вы знаете как решить этот вопрос ?

Comment: Кстати во первых где выбирать страну ? А во вторых у меня всё на английском и по этому страна точно не Россия .

Comment: Разрешение приложению на доступ в интернет в телефоне выдали?

Comment: Нет , а как ? Это в юнити или в телефоне ?

Comment: И ещё ! Может проблема  в юнити ID ? Потому что я на сайте юнити монетизация создал рекламный блок и в нем тоже какой то ID , но в коде я его не указывал . Проверьте пожалуйста .

Comment: Ну что , как мне быть ?

Comment: (((((((((((((((((